# Change ImageView if JSON Object String is equivalent to a value

Tags: android, json

Recently I put together an App and I'm currently scrapping the data from a website including the images. The problem I'm facing is the flags images that are provided on the site look like trash and I'm thinking on fixing this by using the Noto Font Flags (https://code.google.com/p/noto/source/browse/…) to replace the parsed json data
Example:

```
{
"flag": "http://static.hltv.org//images/flag/se.gif"
}
```

if the String data in the JSON Object is equal to "se.jif" then replace ImageView drawable with a local drawable saved locally in the drawable res
Sorry for my poor explanation if you have any additional questions just comment it.

Comment: @karaokyo I don't know how to do it

Comment: @karaokyo I tried making if statements which didn't work out so well

Comment: This problem has been solved